Change the face of the current line in org agenda
Using Doom Emacs.
In org agenda, the line on which the cursor is gets 'highlighted'. But, in my view, just not enough. So, I will like to change the face to something more obvious.
describe-character shows all the character to be in 'hl-line' face! As an aside, that seems wrong. TODO words are in green color, others are not, etc.
So, I customized the 'hl-line' face using:
(custom-set-faces!
  '(hl-line :background "#000000"))

This has an impact on other buffers. But not on the agenda buffer.
How do I customize the highlight of the current line in the agenda? And if possible, I will like this customization to be applicable ONLY to the agenda and ONLY for that theme.

FWIW, I cannot reproduce this: when I set hl-line background to Firebrick Red I get a nice red background on the line of the agenda where my cursor is. I used the Customize interface to do that, but I suppose Doom (or whatever provides custom-set-faces!) does the same thing as custom-set-faces in standard Emacs. I would start with emacs -Q and a minimal Org file added to the agenda list and try the customization again: if that works, then something in your init might be preventing the customization from working - bisect it to find out what.

@NickD Thanks. It finally got solved by adding (add-hook 'org-agenda-mode-hook           (lambda ()             (hl-line-mode)             (face-remap-add-relative 'hl-line :background "#b0e0c6" :foreground "#002a15" :weight 'black))) to the config.
